# Understanding this solution for a trigonometric identity of $\tan2 \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I require help in the area of trigonometry in proving an identity.

I am to prove that the left hand side is equal to $\tan2 \theta$.

I understand up until the second step in this calculation (original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYPpw.png)):

> $$\begin{align*}\text{LHS}&=\frac{\sin 3\theta+\sin\theta}{\cos 3\theta+\cos\theta}\\\\
> &=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{3\theta+\theta}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\theta-\theta}2\right)}{2\cos\left(\frac{3\theta+\theta}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\theta-\theta}2\right)}\\\\
> &=\frac{\sin 2\theta}{\cos2\theta}\\\\
> &=\tan2\theta\\\\
> &=\text{RHS}
> \end{align*}$$

How did they jump from the factor formulae to the double angle one?

I cannot see the relation between those two, am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which part do you find confusing - $\frac {(3 \theta + \theta)} 2 = 2 \theta$, or the factoring out of the common factors?

Comment: I understand the solution completely now thank you, what do you mean by factoring out common factors though?

Comment: I am sure @mathguy means the canceling out of the common factors in the second line (canceling out in the way $\frac{b\cdot a} a =b$)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. You have the 2 in the numerator and the denominator, so it cancels out, and the same with the third factor in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: It might seem silly to ask but how come the 2 thetas with the sin and the cos wasn't cancelled out also?

Comment: **common** factors! normally you could cancel out a statement like $\frac{2\theta} {2\theta}$ but sine you have $\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)}$ the numerator and denominator do not equal, so you can't cancel them out

Comment: Thank you all, you were very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats going on is that there is a miniature u-substitution step in between steps 1 and 2 of the proof. If you let x = θ and y = 3θ then use the fact that

$$\sin (x) + \sin (y) = 2 \sin \frac{x + y}{2}  \cos \frac{x-y}{2}$$,

then re-substitute the original values then you get the second step of the proof.

Comment: you could also add a "\" just before the $sin$ to make it look like a proper $\sin$